# Primefaces extension sheet component on "Enter" press move the focus to the cell in the right

Tags: jsf, primefaces, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

The default operation of the handsontable when press intro is focus the cell on the bottom, but in primefaces extension the focus go to the right, I need go to the bottom, is there some config that I can try?

I tried to modify the afterChange event with the updateSettings method but isn't work.

below the code of the sheet in the JSF way.

```
<pe:sheet extender="sheetExtender" id="sheet" contextMenu="true"
                    rowHeader="true" colHeader="true" widgetVar="sheetWidget"
                    var="_det" rowKey="#{_det.item}" height="300" showRowHeaders="true"
                    value="#{ordenSuministroController.detalles}"
                    readOnly="#{ordenSuministroController.instance.estado!='PENDIENTE'}"
                    converter="#{ordenSuministroDetConverter}"
                    emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros." locale="es-MX"
                    maxCols="5" minCols="5" movableCols="false" movableRows="true">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <strong>HEADER</strong>
                    </f:facet>
                    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Descripcion" required="true"
                        readOnly="#{ordenSuministroController.instance.estado!='PENDIENTE'}"
                        value="#{_det.descripcion}" colType="text"></pe:sheetcolumn>
                    <pe:sheetcolumn headerText="Unidad" value="#{_det.unidad}"
                        readOnly="#{ordenSuministroController.instance.estado!='PENDIENTE'}"
                        colType="text"></pe:sheetcolumn>
</pe:sheet>
```

Primefaces v7.0
Primefaces-extension v7.0.1

Comment: I think you want to use the Sheet Extender functionality and configure the "enterMoves" function: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4531

Comment: Thanks! Here the solution!
`function sheetExtender() {  
       
        this.cfg.enterMoves= {row: 1, col: 0};
    }`

Comment: Nice!  I posted it as the solution for future finders!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on HandsonTable documentation you an use the `enterMoves` function to control how the enter key moves cells.  See: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/4531

Then in the Sheet Extender code you can simply do the "extender" functionality like in the [Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/dynamicColumns.jsf) example and change the Extender to:

```javascript
function sheetExtender() { 
   this.cfg.enterMoves = {row: 1, col: 0}; 
}
```